# Why can't I flip through my embedded gists by changing the src attributes?

Tags: javascript, gist

I am trying to display my gists on my website by allowing the user to flip through them using a left and right arrow button. However when the button is clicked it does not change the gist displayed on my website.

This is the code I have in my JavaScript file.

```
let leftArrowProgram = document.getElementById('left-arrow-program');
let rightArrowProgram = document.getElementById('right-arrow-program');

let programs = ['https://gist.github.com/laurenneoliver/fad062ae77940c38ee82322f0abc63af.js','https://gist.github.com/laurenneoliver/ec55ffa1919e4b5aa92e329dd89a9578.js']

let programTag = document.getElementById('gist-script-tag');

function nextProgram() {
    if (i >= programs.length - 1) {
        return false;
    }
    i++;
    programTag.setAttribute('src', programs[i]);
}
function previousProgram() {
    if (i <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    i--;
    programTag.setAttribute('src', programs[i]);
} 

rightArrowProgram.onclick = nextProgram;
leftArrowProgram.onclick = previousProgram;
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the `i` variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "flip through them"? As in the Gists are embedded on the page in text form? What element is returned by `document.getElementById('gist-script-tag')`? Can the element have a `src` attribute? And if it can, does setting the `src` attribute actually do what you want it to do? If possible, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Assigning the `src` of an existing tag won't load the new script. You need to create a new script tag and append it to the DOM to execute the next gist.